# Get the length of the data received in a buffer with ReadExisting

Tags: vb.net

I need get the length of the received buffer in a serial port in VB. I am using `serial1.ReadExisting()`. The length of the data is variable and does not have a delimiter byte established is a reader `rfid`. The result of `serial1.ReadExisting()` should be an array. How can I put this into variable that changes length, or how get the length of of `serial1.ReadExisting()`?

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documentation on SerialPort.ReadExisting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Dim n As Integer = UhfRfid.BytesToRead
Dim selecatag As Byte() = New Byte(n - 1) {}